# <!DOCTYPE html> - syntax error

Tags: html

why in the world I'm a getting a syntax error from `<!DOCTYPE html>`?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shapes.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="header">


        </div>

        <div class="middle">
            <div class="image">

            </div>
            <div class="text">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Syntax error

```
  File "/Volumes/postergren_projectDrive/Projekt/programmingSandbox/Udacity/Intro to HTML and CSS/startBlock/portfolio/toplist/index.html", line 1
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: "python" -u "/Volumes/postergren_projectDrive/Projekt/programmingSandbox/Udacity/Intro to HTML and CSS/startBlock/portfolio/toplist/index.html"]
[dir: /Volumes/postergren_projectDrive/Projekt/programmingSandbox/Udacity/Intro to HTML and CSS/startBlock/portfolio/toplist]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Comment: Are you running that HTML as Python? What exactly are you doing with the HTML?

Comment: Ohh darn, just realize.. Thanks, my built system in sublime was on python.. That explain it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't output HTML directly from Python. You need to use `print` or better still, a templating library of some sort.

Comment: Thank just realized I made a mistake with the build system in sublime. I had stared my self blind thanks.

Comment: No problem mate, take care.

Answer (score 2):

It was an easy solution, after the first comment i realized it.

It was just a human error, had forgot to set my build system in sublime to chrome instead of anaconda(python).

Thanks..